# relative path for saving the file

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, path

i am copying a photo from my database to a folder in my web application in path `/WebContent/images/temp/nn.png`

my directory structure is

```
friendit/
     WebContent/
               images/
                     temp/
                            nn.png
```

i am saving the image from the controller action class of my web application by to the folder friendit/webcontent/temp/nn.png but i get fileNotFound exception

there is problem with the relative path! 
please help me out with what relative path should i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot directly save the blob type from database to the harddisk directly

try using this,

```
                Blob test=userInfo.getPicture(); //take blob form sql in test variable
                InputStream x=test.getBinaryStream();
                int size=x.available();




                outputStream=new FileOutputStream("./WebContent/images/temp/nn.png");
                byte b[]= new byte[size];
                x.read(b);
                outputStream.write(b);
```